# Read file left to right

Tags: perl

I have a text file formatted so that there are 3 numbers, separated by a space, on each line.
I need my Perl code to read this file sideways and ignore the spaces.

At the moment it is reading downwards and ignoring all the rest of the contents:

```
2 5 10
3 30 60
```

My code would only read 2 and 3.

```
use strict;

open (FILE, shift);
my @contents = <FILE>;

my $first = splice @contents, 0;
my $second = splice @contents, 1;
my $third = splice @contents, 2;
my $total = $first + $second + $third;

print "$total\n";
```

Comment: Post come code so we can see what you're currently trying

Comment: I guarantee you that perl is reading each line of the file, and not just the first character. If you post your code we can tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I have added the code... And I would like for Perl to read as 2 5 10 etc, not as 2 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't specify what you want. I'm guessing you want to values from each row, one row at a time. (2, 5 and 10, then 3, 30 and 60)

I'm not sure that you know what [`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) does.

```
my $first  = splice @contents, 0;
my $second = splice @contents, 1;
my $third  = splice @contents, 2;
```

should be

```
my $first  = splice @fields, 0, 1;
my $second = splice @fields, 0, 1;
my $third  = splice @fields, 0, 1;
```

You didn't specify you only wanted to remove one item, and you didn't account for the index shift that occurs from earlier removals from the array.

There's probably no reason to remove the elements from the array, so that's silly code. You could simply use

```
my $first  = $fields[0];
my $second = $fields[1];
my $third  = $fields[2];
```

Or even

```
my ($first, $second, $third) = @fields;
```

So how does one get the fields from a line? [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html).

```
my @fields = split(' ', $line);
```

All together,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

open(my $FILE, '<', shift) or die $!;
while (<$FILE>) {
   my @fields = split(' ', $_);
   my ($first, $second, $third) = @fields;
   my $total = $first + $second + $third;
   say $total;
}
```

But that can be simplified.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );
use List::Util qw( sum );

while (<>) {
   say sum split;
}
```

References:

- [`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html)
- [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)
- [List::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aUtil)

Comment: Basically, what I'm hoping to get to, is read the contents exactly like you said, and then add the ones in each row together. I appreciate your help

Comment: @Daveid Fred, Yes, I noticed you mentioned that after I started composing my answer. This post answers how to do that in great detail.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
my @contents = <FILE>;
```

You're reading the entire contents of the file into an array. Your array would look like:

```
("2 5 10","3 30 60")
```

At that point, you're trying to do math with strings ... and not getting what you expect.

You need to read each line in a loop and parse out the individual numbers.

```
while (my $line = <FILE>)
{
    chomp($line);
    my ($first, $second, $third) = split(' ', $line);
    ...
}
```

Comment: `split ' '` splits on whitespace, not just single spaces. It's more robust.

Comment: @ikegami, yeah, I went back and forth on that but didn't feel like looking it up ... my perl foo is starting to degrade since I haven't done any of it for a while.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you probably want to read the file one line at a time (though this doesn't really matter with only three lines):

```
while (defined my $line = <FILE>) {
    ...
}
```

next, you need to find the first number in each line. The easiest way to do this is probably `split`

```
my @columns = split(/\h+/, $line);
```

Then you want to grab the first value from each column, and add it to your running total:

```
$total += $columns[0];
```

Or from your edit, maybe you want to sum all the columns, in which case they are `$columns[0]` through `$columns[2]` (Perl counts from 0). So you could write:

```
$total += $columns[0] + $columns[1] + $columns[2]
```

but it'd be easier to use a module instead:

```
use List::Util qw(sum);
$total += sum(@columns);
```

I'm unclear what you want to do with lines other than the first. I'm assuming you want a sum of all the numbers in the file.

There is a very compact way to "sum all numbers in file", like this:

```
use List::Util qw(sum);
$total = sum map { split } <FILE>;
```

but it relies on understanding some more-advanced Perl features.

Answer (score 0):

Files are stored sequentially. Your sample would be stored `2 5 10\n3 30 60` on disk, which is the order the file is read in. You're going to have to read in each line, parse each line into columns, then read the first column from each line.